# google codejam : how to submit answer

Tags: c++, c

i am participating in google codejam 2012. I have red their [Quick start guide](http://code.google.com/codejam/quickstart.html) . But i still unable to understand how to submit the answer. I have following question:

1> It's said that, we have to download the test cases (.in file) and run our program by using it. I just want to know if i have to make a method to extract input from .in file for that or enter it manually to verify the working?

2> When submit our answer, do we have to submit .txt file or .exe file(Am using c language)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry Bo Persson .... i have red it already. but it does not explain my problem well

Comment: I though a section like this was pretty clear: *The ".in" files are simply text files. You are required to write a program that takes the text from the .in file as input and produces some output (as defined by the problem statement). If you would like to look inside the .in file, you can open it in a text editor. Wordpad and Notepad++ will work, as will any other editor that understands UNIX endlines. Warning: Notepad will generally display .in files incorrectly.*

Comment: yes... but still i was not sure if i have to submit the code that extract file to them or not...and it does not answer my 2nd question correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Put the .in files in your program folder.When testing, you don't have to enter it manually (but of course do this). I remember in C there's a method fscanf that can read from a file which might help you.  But when you submit, you should still assume you are reading from the screen (entered manually), that is, change back to scanf.
2.You should submit your .c file.

Comment: [here](http://code.google.com/codejam/faq.html) section:Why might a submission be rejected? point number 5 , it mention i have to submit out put file(which am not sure .txt or .exe ) and not source code(.c file)???

Comment: Try to output to a .out file and submit it.